# WCF project with this sample leads to errors - VS 2008

Tags: wcf

The sample is from here: [link text](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Service/)

I built the sample project and it build with no errors. But click on F5, I get message that the service has been hosted and then it throws this error

AppName: wcfsvchost.exe  AppVer: 9.0.622.1152    ModName: mscorwks.dll
ModVer: 2.0.50727.3082   Offset: 00080012

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of .NET Framework you have installed. WCF requires .NET Framework 3.0 minimum and 3.5 SP1 recomended.

Comment: bychkov:This is what I have: VS 2008 Pro Edition SP 1, .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of your project, there it is possible to select which version for the framework is targeted. Maybe version 2.0 is selected.